# PrimeVue Paginator using index in passthrough

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

Cannot find Paginator pageButton index through Pass Through options.
Am I missing something or it is unavailable at this moment?

https://primevue.org/paginator/

```
pageButton: ({ context }) => {
    return {
      class: [
        'w-14 border rounded border-accent-primary text-accent-primary py-3 items-center self-center flex justify-center leading-4',
        {
          'bg-accent-primary text-neutral-0': context.active,
        },
      ],
      'data-e2e': 'page',
      'data-e2e-page': 'INDEX PLACE',
    };
  },
```

Comment: You are not using PrimeFaces.